# Magento Connect extensions install causes login loop

Tags: magento

I cannot install an extension, it causes a login loop to appear in console.

Screenshots before and after clicking login in console. Any ideas?

Have already tried chmod everything to 777.

Running 1.7.0.2

[image]
[image]

Comment: Works if connecting directly via url on port 8080 (varnish installed)

Answer (score -1):

try remove cache from var/cache in magento base directory.

Comment: Same thing, keeps logging me out.

Comment: remove var/session i forgot about this ;)